# How to get results for each list from "public List<string>[]" with MySql C#

Tags: c#, mysql, list

Hello I'm looking for a little bit of help. I am trying to get results from this piece of code...

```
public List<string>[] SelectPickUp()
{
    string query = "SELECT * FROM pickup";

    List<string>[] list = new List<string>[7];
    list[0] = new List<string>();
    list[1] = new List<string>();
    list[2] = new List<string>();
    list[3] = new List<string>();
    list[4] = new List<string>();
    list[5] = new List<string>();
    list[6] = new List<string>();

    if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            list[0].Add(dataReader["QuestName"] + "");
            list[1].Add(dataReader["QuestId"] + "");
            list[2].Add(dataReader["GiverName"] + "");
            list[3].Add(dataReader["GiverId"] + "");
            list[4].Add(dataReader["MoveToX"] + "");
            list[5].Add(dataReader["MoveToY"] + "");
            list[6].Add(dataReader["MoveToZ"] + "");
        }
        dataReader.Close();
        this.CloseConnection();

        return list;
    }
    else
    {
        return list;
    }
}
```

thing is how do i use the info in another place for example...

```
UInt16 CurrentQuest;
UInt16 SecondQuest;
UInt16 ThridQuest;

if (Questing.Quests.Count == 0)
{
      test.SelectPickUp();
      test.SelectPickUp().list[0].list[0] = CurrentQuest;
      test.SelectPickUp().list[1].list[1] = SecondQuest;
      test.SelectPickUp().list2].list[] = ThridQuest;
}
```

Something of this nature, any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Huh, I can't understand your motivation, but I think that there is a better way to solve your problem.
How about DTO-class?

```
public class Quest
{
    public string QuestName { get; set; }
    public string QuestId { get; set; }
    public string GiverName { get; set; }
    public string GiverId { get; set; }
    public string MoveToX { get; set; }
    public string MoveToY { get; set; }
    public string MoveToZ { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can use more OO-code:

```
var quests = new List<Quest>();
if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
{
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
    MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dataReader.Read())
    {
        var quest = new Quest
        {
            QuestName = (string) dataReader["QuestName"],
            QuestId = (string) dataReader["QuestId"],
            GiverName = (string) dataReader["GiverName"],
            GiverId = (string) dataReader["GiverId"],
            MoveToX = (string) dataReader["MoveToX"],
            MoveToY = (string) dataReader["MoveToY"],
            MoveToZ = (string) dataReader["MoveToZ"]
        };
        quests.Add(quest);

    }
    dataReader.Close();
    this.CloseConnection();

    return quests;
}
```

Next step you can use not only string values. If QuestId is inetger you can cast it to int:

```
QuestId = (int) dataReader["QuestId"],
```

Avoid this code:

```
if (Questing.Quests.Count == 0)
{
    test.SelectPickUp();
    test.SelectPickUp().list[0].list[0] = CurrentQuest;
    test.SelectPickUp().list[1].list[1] = SecondQuest;
    test.SelectPickUp().list2].list[] = ThridQuest;
}
```

You should enumerate reader one time, then try this:

```
var quests = test.SelectPickUp();
if (Questing.Quests.Count == 0)
{
    quests.Insert(0, CurrentQuest);
    quests.Insert(1, SecondQuest);
    quests.Insert(2, ThridQuest);
}
```

Comment: Nvm i See where i didnt change List<string> to List<Quest>

Comment: Can you change return type of your SelectPickUp() method from List<string>[] to List<Quest>() or something like this (IReadOnlyCollection<Quest> may be a good idea)?
And what is your next use-case for the returned value?

Comment: Heres the thing, the SelectPickUp() is one class now on another .CS i have a loop that runs, it checks a XML file for Quests, if the ID it pulls from Mysql does not exist i need to add it to the XML for currentquest and make the var CurrentQuest, SecondQuest, ThridQuest the first three Id's it pulled from mysql. Questing.Quests.Count is the result of the XML.

Comment: OK. This code is totally smelled, mocked and abstracted, but it's compilable and as I can understand can be helpful for you: http://pastie.org/10619042